# Invalid Use of template-name 'node' without an argument list

Tags: c++, class

node.h

```
#ifndef node_h
#define node_h
using namespace std;
template<class Type> 
struct node { 
    node (Type v) : next(nullptr),data(v){}
    Type data; 
    node *next;

    }; 

#endif
```

prioqueueS.cpp

```
#ifndef prioqueueS
#define prioqueueS 
#include "node.h"  
using namespace std;    
template <class type> 
class PrioQueueS { 
private: 
   node *head; 
   node *tail; 
};
#endif
```

This is of course not all of my prioqueue class, but it is the part that I am having issues with, I have looked around on her for a clear answer but haven't found it. This is my error message:

```
error: invalid use of template-name 'node' without an argument list
node *head;
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction for solving this problem that would very appreciated.

EDIT: I realized I forgot the

```
node<Type> head;
```

so I will probably just delete this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node` is a templated type.  To declare a `node` variable (even just a pointer to one), you need to specify a value for the template parameter.  But you are not doing that, so that is what the compiler is complaining about:

```
#ifndef prioqueueS
#define prioqueueS 

#include "node.h"  
using namespace std;    

template <class type> 
class PrioQueueS { 
private: 
   node *head; // <-- here
   node *tail; // <-- here
};

#endif
```

Try this instead:

```
#ifndef prioqueueS
#define prioqueueS 

#include "node.h"  
using namespace std;    

template <class type> 
class PrioQueueS { 
private: 
   node<type> *head; // <-- here
   node<type> *tail; // <-- here
};

#endif
```